# Confusing formatting of inline multiline TeX

Tags: bug, mathjax

[This answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/52758/29) contains the following code:

```
$\mathsf{REG} = \mathsf{DSPACE}(1) = \mathsf{NSPACE}(1) = \mathsf{DSPACE}(o(\log\log n)) = \mathsf{NSPACE}(o(\log\log n))$, where $\mathsf{REG}$ is the set of regular languages.
```

Image:

[image]

Because of the way this is rendered, it appears as if part of the text that's after the formula (`where $\mathsf{REG}$ is the`) was in the middle of the formula.

I'm using FF 43 on Windows 10.

Comment: Huh, weird. It isn't browser-specific, I see the same thing in Chrome on Linux.

Comment: Confirm for FF 44 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Nota bene: long formulae are bound to make problems. This is a particular sad instance since LaTeX is utterly unnecessary here. "REG = DSPACE(1) = ..." is just as readable.